# How to pass an array of objects through a query string and read them in asp.net Controller

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am building an API to generate Invoice Number.

I have the following `InvItem` class

```
public class InvItem
{
    public string ItemCode;
    public double Quantity;
    public double SaleValue;
}
```

I have the following Controller method

```
    [Route("api/InvoiceMaster/GetInvoiceNum")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetInvoiceNum(            
        string xDateTime,
        string BuyerName,
        double TotalBillAmount,            
        InvItem[] items
        )
    {


        ...
        var invItems = new List<InvItem>();
        invItems.AddRange(items);
        ...
        return Ok();            
    }
```

Invoice can have one or more items. Now I want to call that method from postman (or any other application) using `GET` request.

I have already built that method using `POST` request and reading parameters from request body. But the requirement here is STRICTLY Get Request.

I have tried the following url but **cannot get the value of items** in controller's action method 'GetInvoiceNum'

```
https://localhost:44365/api/InvoiceMaster/GetInvoiceNum?xDateTime=2020-01-01 12:00:00&BuyerName=elon&TotalBillAmount=1519&items[0].ItemCode=001897&items[0].Quantity=1&items[0].SaleValue=19&items[1].ItemCode=002899&items[1].Quantity=1&items[1].SaleValue=1500
```

How can I pass this array of objects to api?

Comment: If someone insists on forcing this to be a GET then you will need to encode data to be URL friendly and then decode it back to your array on the server. You could for instance convert it to json then base64 url encode it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add from [FromQuery]

```
public IActionResult GetInvoiceNum(            
        [FromQuery] string xDateTime,
        [FromQuery] string BuyerName,
        [FromQuery] double TotalBillAmount,            
        [FromQuery] InvItem[] items
        )
```

and convert fields to properties by adding getters/setters

```
public class InvItem
    {
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public double Quantity { get; set; }
        public double SaleValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This solved my problem using the same url as given in the question.